# .NET Core razor pages adding a dropdownlist and populating it from sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to make the `City` attribute a dropdownlist attribute which is populated by my local sql server. What should I change in my code?

By the way, I'm using **ASP.NET Core 3.1 and a local SQL Server database** in my project. And **please answer with Razor Pages format, not MVC format**.

My `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Inside of `Models/Person/create.cshtml`:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Person.City" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Person.City" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Person.City" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Inside of `Models/Person/edit.cshtml`:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Person.City" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Person.City" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Person.City" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: _What should I change in my code?_ - to do what?

Comment: to change city attribute from normal text input to dropdown list input which is populated by database(city names will be populated)

Comment: So why not use a [`select`](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/use-select-dropdown-in-aspdotnet-razor)?

Comment: Because i don't know how to use it and adapt to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo:

```
public class ListModel : PageModel
{
        [BindProperty]
        public SelectList Cities { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            
            Cities = new SelectList(_context.Cities.ToList(), "City", "City");
        }
}
```

cshtml:

```
<select asp-for="Person.City" asp-items=@Model.Cities ></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this in the view file :

```
<select asp-for="Person.CityId" class="form-control" 
 asp-items="ViewBag.CityId"></select>
```

and in the Razor Page or Controller use something like this.

```
ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Cities, 
 "CityId", "CityId", Person.CityId);
```

You can adapt this code with your model. This is working in my MVC project, so I thing you can easily adapt it to Razor Page.